# Ignore type class

Tags: java, json, gson

```
@JsonIgnoreType 
public class Name implements User
 {
    private int uid;
    private String homename;
 }
}
```

I need to use gson instead of Json in order to ignore property of type Name.
Can anyone help me in this?